# nodejs + socketio + peerjs - a simple code not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, peerjs

I have been dealing with making a simple boiler plate code to work. The nodejs server has been hosted locally. I was able to make socket connection using socket.io successfully. But no matter what the webRTC connection using peerJS is not getting initiated.

The below piece of code is not working at all, the callback is not getting triggered. I have tried everything possible, but nothing helps. Can anyone help me find a clue?

Does corporate proxy has any role in this? I am working on my company machine, that has a default proxy set and disabled.

```
myPeer.on('open', id => {});
```

Please find the full code below.

***server-side:***

```
const socket = require('socket.io');
const express = require('express');
const peer = require('peer');
const http = require('http');

const PORT = 9000;

const expressApp = express();
const expressServer = http.Server(expressApp);
const socketServer = socket(expressServer);
const peerServer = peer.ExpressPeerServer(expressServer, { debug: true });

expressApp.use('/peerjs', peerServer)
expressApp.get('/stream/:streamId', (req, res) => {
 res.render('stream', { streamId: req.params.streamId });
});

expressServer.listen(PORT);

socketServer.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, peerId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).emit('user-connected', peerId);
  });
});
```

**client-side**

*html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>streamophone</title>
  <script>const ROOM_ID = "<%= streamId %>";</script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='video' style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column;">
    <h1>New stream starts here! <%= streamId %></h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*js:*

```
const setupSocketConnectionViaPeer = (socket, myPeer) => {
  myPeer.on('open', id => {
    console.log(id);
    socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID);
  });
};

const setupSocketEvents = (socket) => {
  socket.on('user-connected', (peerId) => {
    console.log('some-one else has been connected', peerId);
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function () {
  const socket = io('/');
  const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, { path: '/peerjs', host: '/', port: 9000 });

  setupSocketConnectionViaPeer(socket, myPeer);
  setupSocketEvents(socket);
});
```

Version info:

```
peer.js(front-end): 1.3.1
peer.js(back-end): 0.6.1
socket.io(front-end): N/A
socket.io(back-end): 4.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is months old but I just came across this and tested it.

Except that you missed sending peer ID in the below line, others seem okay.

*socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, **id**);*

These what I ran

**peer-server.js**

```js
const socket = require('socket.io');
const express = require('express');
const peer = require('peer');
const http = require('http');

const PORT = 9000;

const expressApp = express();
const expressServer = http.Server(expressApp);
const socketServer = socket(expressServer, {
  path: '/socket.io'
});
const peerServer = peer.ExpressPeerServer(expressServer, { debug: true });

// View engine setup
expressApp.set('view engine', 'ejs');

expressApp.use(express.static('public'))

expressApp.use('/peerjs', peerServer)
expressApp.get('/stream/:streamId', (req, res) => {
 res.render('stream', { streamId: req.params.streamId });
});

expressServer.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})

socketServer.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, peerId) => {
    console.log('someone joined the room ', roomId, peerId);
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).emit('user-connected', peerId);
  });
});
```

**/public/script.js**

```js
console.log('JS loaded');

const setupSocketConnectionViaPeer = (socket, myPeer) => {
  myPeer.on('open', id => {
    console.log('Peer ID:', id);
    socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id);
  });
};

const setupSocketEvents = (socket) => {
  socket.on('user-connected', (peerId) => {
    console.log('some-one else has been connected', peerId);
    const userElement = document.createElement('div')
    userElement.innerText = `New user connected : ${peerId}`
    
    const userListElement = document.getElementById('userList')
    userListElement.appendChild(userElement)
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function () {
  const socket = io('/');
  const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, { path: '/peerjs', host: '/', port: 9000 });

  setupSocketConnectionViaPeer(socket, myPeer);
  setupSocketEvents(socket);
});
```

/views/stream.ejs

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>streamophone</title>
  <script>const ROOM_ID = "<%= streamId %>";</script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='video' style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column;">
    <h1>New stream starts here! <%= streamId %></h1>
    <div id="userList"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "peerjs-socketio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon peer-server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "peer": "^0.6.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
  }
}
```

Testing

```
npm i
npm run dev
```

Access with browser => http://localhost:9000/stream/1

[image: The result every time someone joined]